# Iterating over multiple-line string stored in variable

Tags: bash, read

I [read](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29) that it is bad to write things like `for line in $(command)`, the correct way seem to be instead:

```
command | while IFS= read -r line; do echo $line; done
```

This works great. But what if what I want to iterate on is the contents of a **variable**, not the direct result of a command?

For example, imagine that you create the following file `quickfox`:

```
The quick brown
foxjumps\ over -
the
lazy ,
dog.
```

I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
# This is just for the example,
# I could of course stream the contents to `read`
variable=$(cat quickfox);
while IFS= read -r line < $variable; do echo $line; done; # this is incorrect
```

Answer (score 70, accepted):

In modern shells like bash and zsh, you have a very useful `<<<' redirector that accepts a string as an input. So you would do

```
while IFS= read -r line ; do echo $line; done <<< "$variable"
```

Otherwise, you can always do

```
echo "$variable" | while IFS= read -r line ; do echo $line; done
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have thought about echoing the contents of course. But thanks for the quick answer anyway!

Comment: you need to double-quote `$variable` when you use it, otherwise the `while` loop will get only one line of input.  See, for example, the difference in output between `echo $variable` vs `echo "$variable"` or `cat <<< $variable` vs `cat <<< "$variable"`.

Comment: @cas Actually it depends on what is inside $variable. In the case presented by the OP ("variable=$(cat quickfox)") it works without the additional quotes. But for the general case, you're right. I edit my answer. Thanks.

Comment: The `variable=$(cat quickfox)` in the OP's question itself provides an example of what I was talking about.  Using that `$variable` inside double-quotes includes the newlines, using it without has the newlines translated to spaces by the shell.  If you're reading and processing line-by-line, this makes a huge difference - with the former you have multiple input lines, with the latter you have just one input line.  The input data is superficially similar but, in practice, completely different in those two cases.

Comment: for example: with that input data, `cat <<< "$variable" | wc -l` returns 5.  `cat <<< $variable | wc -l` returns 1.  If you want/need to preserve whitespace (including newlines, tabs, single or multiple spaces) in a variable then you MUST double-quote the variable when you use it, otherwise they'll all be transformed into a single space between each "word".

Comment: @cas My shell (zsh 5.2 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)) outputs 5 in both cases.

Comment: The OP uses `bash` (as do I and the majority of linux and osx users), and the question is tagged with `/bash`, not `/zsh`.

Answer (score 4):

Example how to iterate over env variables with multi-line values:

```
for var in $(compgen -v | grep -Ev '^(BASH)'); do
    echo "$var=${!var}"
done
```

Explained:

1. `$(compgen -v | grep -Ev '^(BASH)')` - grep a list of env **keys**, skip those that started with `BASH`
2. `echo "$var=${!var}"` - print **key**=**value** pairs

Comment: That's adding a lot of complexity to your answer while you have a simple data sample in the question XD